# Solving maximum weighted matching with capacity > 1 in GLPK

Tags: glpk

When solving a regular maximum weighted matching problem in GLPK, one would provide a DIMACS file and call glp_asnprob_lp with GLP_ASN_MMP. However, this will set all the constrains to <= 1, for example 
Subject To
r_1: + x(1,9) + x(1,10) + x(1,12) <= 1
r_2: + x(2,10) + x(2,12) + x(2,13) <= 1
r_3: + x(3,11) + x(3,13) <= 1
r_4: + x(4,9) + x(4,12) + x(4,14) <= 1

I want each node to have a higher capacity (say 10), hence the constrains would be: 
Subject To
r_1: + x(1,9) + x(1,10) + x(1,12) <= 10
r_2: + x(2,10) + x(2,12) + x(2,13) <= 10
r_3: + x(3,11) + x(3,13) <= 10
r_4: + x(4,9) + x(4,12) + x(4,14) <= 10

How do I go about it? I really don't want to have to build my own matrix.